# debugging openJDK9 with lldb，can't step into the method JLI_Launch

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, lldb

I recently got the source code of openJDK9, and I compiled successfully with slowDebug Mode. Here is result
[compiled directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF9To.png)

I debug the launcher java with lldb, here is the command.

```
cd /Users/chenyongda/Desktop/openjdk/openJDK9/YourOpenJDK/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-serverANDclient-slowdebug/jdk/bin

lldb ./java
```

and then, it works! Here is the result.

[lldb-breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElUvk.png)

That is cool! However, in this c file named main.c, I can only step over the code. If I want to step into the specific code which for example **JLI_Launch**, it goes over all the time

Related code I listed below
main.c

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int margc;
    char** margv;
    const jboolean const_javaw = JNI_FALSE;
#endif /* JAVAW */
    JLI_InitArgProcessing(!HAS_JAVA_ARGS, const_disable_argfile);
#ifdef _WIN32
{
    int i = 0;
    if (getenv(JLDEBUG_ENV_ENTRY) != NULL) {
        printf("Windows original main args:\n");
        for (i = 0 ; i < __argc ; i++) {
            printf("wwwd_args[%d] = %s\n", i, __argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
JLI_CmdToArgs(GetCommandLine());
margc = JLI_GetStdArgc();
// add one more to mark the end
margv = (char **)JLI_MemAlloc((margc + 1) * (sizeof(char *)));
{
    int i = 0;
    StdArg *stdargs = JLI_GetStdArgs();
    for (i = 0 ; i < margc ; i++) {
        margv[i] = stdargs[i].arg;
    }
    margv[i] = NULL;
}
#else /* *NIXES */
{
    // accommodate the NULL at the end
    JLI_List args = JLI_List_new(argc + 1);
    int i = 0;

    // Add first arg, which is the app name
    JLI_List_add(args, JLI_StringDup(argv[0]));
    // Append JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS
    if (JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar(args, JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS)) {
        // JLI_SetTraceLauncher is not called yet
        // Show _JAVA_OPTIONS content along with JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS to aid diagnosis
        if (getenv(JLDEBUG_ENV_ENTRY)) {
            char *tmp = getenv("_JAVA_OPTIONS");
            if (NULL != tmp) {
                JLI_ReportMessage(ARG_INFO_ENVVAR, "_JAVA_OPTIONS", tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    // Iterate the rest of command line
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        JLI_List argsInFile = JLI_PreprocessArg(argv[i]);
        if (NULL == argsInFile) {
            JLI_List_add(args, JLI_StringDup(argv[i]));
        } else {
            int cnt, idx;
            cnt = argsInFile->size;
            for (idx = 0; idx < cnt; idx++) {
                JLI_List_add(args, argsInFile->elements[idx]);
            }
            // Shallow free, we reuse the string to avoid copy
            JLI_MemFree(argsInFile->elements);
            JLI_MemFree(argsInFile);
        }
    }
    margc = args->size;
    // add the NULL pointer at argv[argc]
    JLI_List_add(args, NULL);
    margv = args->elements;
}
#endif /* WIN32 */
return JLI_Launch(margc, margv,
               sizeof(const_jargs) / sizeof(char *), const_jargs,
               0, NULL,
               VERSION_STRING,
               DOT_VERSION,
               (const_progname != NULL) ? const_progname : *margv,
               (const_launcher != NULL) ? const_launcher : *margv,
               HAS_JAVA_ARGS,
               const_cpwildcard, const_javaw, 0);
}
```

and the next snippet is in java.c

```
int
JLI_Launch(int argc, char ** argv,              /* main argc, argc */
    int jargc, const char** jargv,          /* java args */
    int appclassc, const char** appclassv,  /* app classpath */
    const char* fullversion,                /* full version defined */
    const char* dotversion,                 /* UNUSED dot version 
    defined */
    const char* pname,                      /* program name */
    const char* lname,                      /* launcher name */
    jboolean javaargs,                      /* JAVA_ARGS */
    jboolean cpwildcard,                    /* classpath wildcard*/
    jboolean javaw,                         /* windows-only javaw */
    jint ergo                               /* unused */
)
{
    int mode = LM_UNKNOWN;
    char *what = NULL;
    char *main_class = NULL;
    int ret;
```

I love openJdk, and I really want to debug in deep to find out the detail about how java work. Hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have debug information for the JLI_Launch function?

You can tell that by doing:

```
(lldb) image lookup -vn JLI_Launch
```

If you have debug information for this function, then the output of this command will show entries for the CompileUnit and the LineEntry.  If those entries are missing, then at least that function was built without debug information.

If you have a pre-built openJDK it's not too surprising if that didn't have debug information.  Sometimes pre-built binaries have a side package with debug info?  But even so pre-built binaries are usually built with optimization on, and if you are actually trying to step through the library to understand it, you will be happier with a version that's built without optimization.  It's considerably harder to understand code flow with an optimized binary.

If you are building your own version, you need to figure out how to get the build to generate debug info.  I have never built this library so I can't help you with that but presumably somebody on the openJDK mailing lists will know.

Note also, by default, lldb always steps over functions that don't have debug information. But if you pass the "-a 0" flag to the step command, it will reverse this default:

```
(lldb) step -a 0
```

But if you actually want to understand how the code works, you will want to get your hands on a debug build.